# SSRS - how to check if a row is toggled or visible?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a drill-down report in SSRS 2008 and I want to do some conditional formatting on the main row. For example, if it's not toggled add a different background color and different border.

I haven't been able to figure out how I can check if the current row is expanded or not using an expression.

[image: How to use different formatting when toggled and not toggled?]

Comment: I'm not sure you can: the client browser does the toggle so the info isn't available at render time for your expression. Maybe there is some javascript solution you can add to the page but I doubt it

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick(check the result to see if it's ok for you. this solutions leaves a small space when the group is expanded) :

Add an extra column at the left for expand collapse.

Add a second row in the group with color.

Set expand/collapse only to the first row textbox

In the expand/collapse column set the second row textbox visibility to hidden.

Set the first controls(only at the textboxes) visibility to visible and the second to hidden, except the column with expand collapse. Set the first row textbox as the toggle item

Set both rows height to 0 (althought is will be automatically set to a very small value)

Now your report should look like the image below

[image]