# Decoration of the text, provided that the visibility = true

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

It seems to me to be fairly simple, but never manages to decorate the text modes, under some conditions the visibility of a detail table

following picture: A view of where the visibility is set
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, the problem would have solved if I could write: =IIF(table1.nameOfDetailRow.visibility = true, "none", "underline")

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand... if it's visible, you want it underlined, and otherwise, you don't?  What's wrong with just underlining it?  Invisible text's styles probably don't show if the text itself is also invisible.

Comment: You can't use vb code to check visibility of report items. @bdares I think he wants to underline the group when detail is expanded

Comment: @tihoroot, in case I am right and you want to underline groups when detail is expanded, please confirm

Comment: you're right, I  want to underline groups when detail is expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

```
* Add a second row to the group.
* Set the top border to single, the rest to none
* Set the visibility to hidden.
* Set the height to 0
* Set it to expand/collapse like the detail.
```

By doing the steps above, the second row will be hidden like the detail and expand with it.

When it is expanded it will show the top border, which will look like an underline (continued)

Comment: This trick does not solve my problem. for me, I need to set the text decoration properties, provided that the details are visible or not.
thank you for time spent, this kind of stuff I need =IIF(table1.nameOfDetailRow.visibility = true, "none", "underline")

Comment: There is a similar question and answer with color. Check if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456461/ssrs-how-to-check-if-a-row-is-toggled-or-visible

Comment: Unfortunately direct reference to objects through vb code is not possible

Comment: I could not find an adequate solution, but thank you for your help.